# Stop auto sync of Date and Time on windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, datetime, time, virtual-machine

I have a requirement where I want to run a test case in PDT time. So I tried to change date and time of my windows machine(a VM) but it gets automatically reverted back to current date and time . I want a help regarding that.

I have time server sync. checkbox off as well as windows time service and hypervisor time service is also off on the VM.

Please post your thoughts

Comment: Why not change the time*zone* of the VM ?

Comment: I changed the timezone. But I want to change the date and time in that particular timezone